# why doesn't this code receive string ?(it just receive the first character)

Tags: atmega, uart, interrupts

I want to receive a string whit atmega8 that is sent by another atmega8. The sender send string just one time, but in receiver just first character is received. I can't understand what is the problem?
thanks for your help.
this is the code.

```
// USART Receiver interrupt service routine
interrupt [USART_RXC] void usart_rx_isr(void)
{ 
   while ( !(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)));

   for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
     data = UDR;  
     if (data != '\0') {
       mass[i]=data; 
     }

     while ( !(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)));   
   }
   lcd_puts(mass);
   delay_ms(500);
   lcd_clear();
}
```

and while loop is empty . I try to use interrupt to receive.

Comment: You can't wait for characters inside the ISR this way.

Comment: You should add the byte received to a buffer, you are doing way too much inside the ISR. The LCD functions, delays, and clear should not be in the ISR, and don't wait for more data in the ISR, it will get called when more data comes in.

Comment: Apart from issues notes by others (don't wait in an interrupt!!): where do you increment the i ?

Comment: I thank all of you. I can receive string by this code when sender send string frequently whit 500 ms delay. but this code faces problem when sender send just one time .

Comment: Matt Young thank for your comment but what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Interrupts are designed to do a short bit of work and then leave.  You might think of them as an add-on to the main-loop-only structure.  For example:

```
void main(void)
{
    //startup initialization
    while(1)
    {
        if(flag1)
        {
            flag1 = 0;
            //do something triggered by flag1
        }
        if(flag2)
        {
            flag2 = 0;
            switch(flag2_state)
            {
            case 0:
                //do action0 from flag2
                break;
            case 1:
                //do action1 from flag2
                break;
            //etc.
            default:
                //correct an invalid state
                break;
            }
            flag2_state++;
        }
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Notice how `flag2`'s handler does different things each time it's triggered, but always leaves to allow the rest of the code to keep running.  This is the difference between running on "bare metal" as you are, and running on a multithreaded task manager like you would have as part of an operating system like Windows, Mac, or Linux.  Once you understand that, then we can introduce interrupts:

```
void main(void)
{
    //startup initialization
    while(1)
    {
        if(flag1)
        {
            flag1 = 0;
            //do something triggered by flag1
        }
        //etc.
    }
}
interrupt [flag2] void flag2_isr(void)
{
    flag2 = 0;
    switch(flag2_state)
    {
    case 0:
        //do action0 from flag2
        break;
    case 1:
        //do action1 from flag2
        break;
    //etc.
    default:
        //correct an invalid state
        break;
    }
    flag2_state++;
}
```

I'm making some assumptions here about the syntax, but I think you get the idea.  The whole point of interrupts is to reduce the latency of certain events, or in other words, the time it takes to handle them.

In the first example, if `flag1` and `flag2` were to both come on immediately after you check `flag2`, and `flag1` takes a long time to process, then `flag2` would have to wait that long to even start.  That might not be acceptable.

In the second example, `flag2` is handled immediately, even if `flag1` is still processing.  But it becomes much more important to actually leave the ISR because it completely blocks the main loop from doing anything.

Physically, an interrupt is a function-call that is done automatically by the hardware in response to `flag2`.  Because this can happen at any time without warning, you have to design the interaction well to avoid some weird bugs.  (the `volatile` keyword is really helpful here)  It's also more important than before to clear `flag2`, or the function-call will happen again, and again, and again, burning through the state machine like it wasn't even there, and blocking main loop almost as if you're not leaving the ISR at all.

---

Once you understand that, I can explain that the reason that blocking code (your original example) works on a multitasking operating system (there are several ways to do it; this is just one of them) is that the OS has a user-invisible interrupt that is triggered from a timer.  This can do all sorts of things that are based on a time interval, in addition to switching tasks.  To make the switch, just save the stack pointer (which context am I running in?) to an OS-managed library and load a different one from that same library.  Now when the ISR leaves, it goes to a different task.  Thus, each task can be written as if it's the only thing running.  Not so on bare metal because you don't have that context switcher.